# How to extract text from jsonb array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I want to be able to extract text from jsonb array in a new column as text.
This is my SQL table.

| Id. | ErrorCode. |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | `["exit code: 1"]` |
| 102 | `["exit code: 3"]` |
| 103 | `["OOMKILLED"]` |

This is my column definition  `'[]'::jsonb`

I needed help understanding which select command I could use in that case. I used the query above but with no success.

`Select reasons -> '  ' as TTT from my_table`

I want to get these results after a select command., so I can do SQL filters like
`where error = 'exit code: 1'`  or `where error = 'OOMKILLED'`

| Id. | Error |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | exit code: 1 |
| 102 | exit code: 3 |
| 103 | OOMKILLED |

Comment: Please look is this can help you: https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/1755601cc7fe390ff2d136160f28cafb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `->>` to extract the first array element as text:

```
Select id, reasons ->> 0 as reason
from my_table
where reasons ->> 0 in ('exit code: 1','OOMKILLED');
```

If you don't want to repeat the expression use a derived table:

```
select * 
from (
  select id, reasons ->> 0 as reason
  from my_table
) 
where reason in ('exit code: 1','OOMKILLED');
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly the query i need

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT Id, jsonb_array_elements_text(ErrorCode :: jsonb) AS Error
  FROM my_table
```

For more info about json functions see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING)

Comment: Thanks  when I'm running this suggested query, I'm getting this error 
'[22023] ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar'

Comment: cab you share the definition of your table please ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error:
ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar

Comment: Hey,
This is my column definition  `'[]'::jsonb`

Answer (score 0):

When you need check is JSONB array contains some value, just use ? operator:

```
select * from t where err ? 'OOMKILLED';
```

https://sqlize.online/s/eW